# Why is my useContext not working in my app and my browser remains loading?

Tags: reactjs, use-context

Im trying to use useContext hook to pass variables and functions through different components without lifting them to the main App.js component. I was trying to do this and it seemed to compile correctly but when i go to my browser my app is stucked in a blank page and remains loading.

LoginContext.js: In this component i store the user data in an object using the useState hook and i use jwt_decode to decode the use token and get all the data i need to store.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';



const LoginContext = createContext();

export function LoginProvider({children}) {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        var userData = jwt_decode(response.credential); //Token with the login user Data
        setUser(userData); //Store user Data 
        /* console.log(userData) */
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = true;
        
      }

    function handleSignOut(event) {
        setUser({}) //Empy the user Data
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = false;
    }  

    return(
        <LoginProvider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut}}>{children}</LoginProvider>
    );
}

export default LoginContext
```

The i have my Login.js which uses LoginContext: Here i use the user to show the different data of the logged in use and the handleCallbackResponse to do my Login.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'

import LoginContext from '../LoginContext';

const Login = () => {
  
  const {user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut} = useContext(LoginContext)

      useEffect(()=>{
        /*global google*/
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id:"My client ID",
          callback: handleCallbackResponse
        })
    
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
    
    
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById('signInDiv'),
          {theme: 'outline', size: 'medium'}
        )
    
      }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <div id="signInDiv"></div>
      {
        //If user objetc is not empty show sign out button
        Object.keys(user).length !== 0 &&
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleSignOut(e)}>Sign Out</button>
      }
      {user && 
        <div>
          <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './atoms/Login';
import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import { LoginProvider } from './LoginContext';
import PrivateRoutes from './utils/PrivateRoutes';

function App() {
  return (
    <LoginProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
        </Route> */}
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
        <Route  path="/" element={<Login/>} />    
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </LoginProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For some reason my application runs with no error but in the browser it remains loading with a blank page and im not able to inspect the page.

Comment: Could it be because your `LoginProvider` is returning `<LoginProvider ...>` so its returning itself?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<LoginProvider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut}}>{children}</LoginProvider>
);
```

Replace with

```
<LoginContext.Provider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut}}>{children}</LoginContext.Provider>
```